# Python - How do I use variables in font render commands?

Tags: python, fonts, pygame, display

New python programmer here. I'm adding something to my code so that that the user will be able to keep track  of their score, but I not really sure what I'm supposed to do for this one part.
Here's some parts of my code:

```
number_enemies = 15
objective = (number_enemies, "enemies left")

font = pygame.font.SysFont('Comic_sans', 100, True, False)
enemies_left = font.render(objective, True, RED)

screen.blit(enemies_left, [900, 900])
```

What I want this to do, is to display the text "15 enemies left" on the screen, so that that I can incorporate it into my game, but I can't get it to work.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`render` expects `string` - you have to create it - `"%d enemies left" % number_enemies`

```
 number_enemies = 15

 # create only once
 font = pygame.font.SysFont('Comic_sans', 100, True, False)

 # mainloop

     # create string
     objective = "%d enemies left" % number_enemies

     # render image with text
     enemies_left = font.render(objective, True, RED)

     # blit image
     screen.blit(enemies_left, [900, 900])
```

Answer (score 1):

Just do:

`objective = str(number_enemies) + " enemies left"`

The render function expects a string, but you are giving it a tuple (Immutable list) by putting the variables in parentheses. You need to add the string value of `number_enemies` to your other text.